# Como prevenir un undefined. ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listaAvisos')

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando con Angular y tengo un servicio que me trae como respuesta este tipo de objeto:

```
{  
"totalAvisos": 25,  
"success": true,  
"avisos": "[{\"numeroAviso\": 365895,\"placa\": \"YHE484\",\"numeroSiniestro\": \"TER4475145\",\"tallerIdAdmin\": 325,\"fechaSiniestro\": 1639151373000,\"procesoReparacion\": \"Vehículo Entregado\",\"repuestosPendiente\": \"5 de 10\"}, {\"numeroAviso\": 365895,\"placa\": \"YHE484\",\"numeroSiniestro\": \"TER4475145\",\"tallerIdAdmin\": 325,\"fechaSiniestro\": 1639151373000,\"procesoReparacion\": \"Vehículo Entregado\",\"repuestosPendiente\": \"5 de 10\"}, {\"numeroAviso\": 365895,\"placa\": \"YHE484\",\"numeroSiniestro\": \"TER4475145\",\"tallerIdAdmin\": 325,\"fechaSiniestro\": 1639151373000,\"procesoReparacion\": \"Vehículo Entregado\",\"repuestosPendiente\": \"5 de 10\"}]",  
"message": "Consulta de avisos exitosa"  
};
```

En el mismo servicio haga la conversion con un JSON.parse para un string y los parametros los tengo en esta funcion:

```
// Componente Padre
    // Funcion
    getVehicleOutOfWorkshop(tallerId: string, cantidadRegistros: number, pagina: number) {
        let data = {
            "tallerId": tallerId,
            "cantidadRegistros": cantidadRegistros,
            "pagina": pagina
        };
        this.inboxNoticeService.getNoticeOutsideWorkshop(data).then((res: any) => {
            this.varForFunction = res;
            console.log("respuesta servicio fuera del taller", res);
            // console.log(data);
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log("error para obtener respuesta del servicio", err);
        });
    }

   // Esto es un evento click, de igual manera ya funciona por lo que comento mas abajo.
    selectedSubTab(tab: string){
        this.subtab = tab
        this.getVehicleOutOfWorkshop('216', 10, 1)
    }
```

Los datos que me arroja el objeto por medio de la variable varForFunction los integro a una interfaz como esta:

```
// Variable
// Componente Padre
varForFunction: Notice;

// La interfaz esta en otro archivo
// Interfaz
export interface Notice { 
    total: number,
    avisos: string,
    listaAvisos: NoticeItem[],
    success: boolean,
    message: string
}

export interface NoticeItem{
   numeroAviso: number,
   creacionAviso: number,
   placa: string,
   numeroSiniestro: string,
   nombreTaller: string,
   diasEnTaller: number,
   fechaSiniestro: number,
   estadoProcesReparacion: string,
   fechaCritico: number,
   criticoId: number,
   repuestosFaltantes: string | null,
   existenFechasDeReparacion: boolean,
   aseguradoraId: number,
   diasCritico: number | null
}
```

La variable varForFunction la utilizo para enviar los datos de mi componente padre a mi componente hijo:

```
// Esta parte esta en el HTML de mi componente Padre
[resOfFunction]="varForFunction"

// Esto es mi del Ts del componente Hijo
    @Input() resOfFunction: Notice = {
        message:'',
        total:0,
        listaAvisos:[] = [],
        avisos:"",
        success:true
    };
```

y por ultimo utilizo un ngFor para poder visualizar los datos que necesito, ¿Cuales son?: necesito el dato de totalAvisos y lo que se encuentra en **avisos** que ahi esta el error por que cuando hago el ngFor para recorrer los **avisos** me arroja un error como este:

[image: Imagen del error en la consola]

De igual manera puede ver en el navegador lo que necesito pero necesito solucionar ese error, aqui mi html:

```
<div class="border-main-card mt-4">
    <div class="header-main-card align-items-center px-3 pt-3">
        <span class="text-header-main">Repuestos pendientes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="px-3">
        <div class="row pt-3 pb-3">
            <!-- Contador interno de avisos -->
            <div class="col-6 text-left align-self-center">
                <span class="text-sucursals">Total Avisos</span>
                <span class="pill-custom px-3 py-1 ml-3">{{resOfFunction.total}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Tabla de avisos -->
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="d-flex pt-3 pb-3 mb-3 border-row border-l-gray custom-row shadow-row" *ngFor="let item of resOfFunction.listaAvisos">
                <div class="w-15 text-center">
                    <span class="txt-row-tlt">Placa</span>
                    <span class="txt-row-res ml-2 pr-3 border-right">{{item.placa}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-22 d-flex">
                    <span class="txt-row-tlt">Siniestro</span>
                    <div class="w-100 border-right mr-2 h-17">
                        <span class="txt-row-res ml-2 pr-2">{{item.numeroSiniestro}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-22 d-flex align-items-start tooltip-white">
                    <img src="/o/sgto-inbox-notice-list/icons/ico_house_car.svg" width="20">
                    <div class="txt-row-res2 ml-2 pr-2 border-right h-17 ">
                        Compañia chiricana de...
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Compañia Chiricana de repuestos originales y de segunda mano, sede
                            Teusaquillo LTDA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-13 tooltip-blue pl-3">
                    <img src="/o/sgto-inbox-notice-list/icons/ico_calendar.svg" width="15" class="img-crit">
                    <span class="txt-calendar ml-2 pr-4 border-right pt-1">{{item.fechaSiniestro | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</span>
                    <div class="tooltiptext right-position">
                        <div class="header-tooltip">
                            Fecha
                        </div>
                        <div class="body-tooltip">
                            Autorizacion del aviso
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-15">
                    <div class="border-right h-17 pr-3">
                        <span class="txt-stage ml-2">{{item.estadoProcesReparacion}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-7 text-center tooltip-blue-parts">
                    <div class="h-17 border-right">
                        <img src="/o/sgto-inbox-notice-list/icons/ico_repuestos_tooltip.svg" width="26"
                            class="img-crit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tooltiptext">
                        <div class="header-tooltip">
                            Repuestos
                        </div>
                        <div class="body-tooltip row text-center">
                            <span class="col-12">Faltantes</span>
                            <span class="col-12 mt-n2">{{item.repuestosFaltantes}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w-5 text-center">
                    <img src="/o/sgto-inbox-notice-list/icons/ico_arrow_right.svg" width="12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Me dijeron que para solucionar el error utilizara un ngOnChange con eso puedo prevenir en undefined pero no entiendo como tratar eso.

Comment: Para no obtener ese error la variable debe estar asignada primero.

Comment: @Mateo explicate por favor, con ejemplo asi me cuesta mas

Comment: Si quieres a la casa de un amigo pero no te la dirección. ¿Cómo haces para ir a su casa? Simplemente no puedes porque no la sabes (a menos que te lleve él, claro). Bueno, algo similar pasa con las variables. Las variables contienen referencias (son como las direcciones de las casas). Si no asignas la variable, no tiene ninguna referencia. Eso es lo que representa `undefined`. Entonces el programa no tiene idea de dónde leer el campo `listaAvisos` porque primero necesita saber la dirección del objeto (la casa en la analogía).

Comment: @Mateo depronto no viste el codigo pero listaAvisos esta referenciado de esta manera: listaAvisos[] eso esta dentro de la interfaz

Comment: Solo mencioné el significado del error ya que no deja de ser Javascript y no sé de angular. Quizá te servía para encontrar lo que está mal.